# Parsing CSV with headers in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, parsing, csv

This works:

```
    require 'csv'
    file = CSV.open(filename)
    puts file.shift
```

This does not:

```
    require 'csv'
    file = CSV.open(filename, :headers=>true)
    puts file.shift
```

I get:

```
C:/Program Files (x86)/IronRuby 1.1/Lib/ruby/1.9.1/csv.rb:2177:in `convert_field
s': undefined method `with_index' for IronRuby.Builtins.Enumerator:Enumerator (N
oMethodError)
    from C:/Program Files (x86)/IronRuby 1.1/Lib/ruby/1.9.1/csv.rb:2218:in `
parse_headers'
    from C:/Program Files (x86)/IronRuby 1.1/Lib/ruby/1.9.1/csv.rb:1918:in `
shift'
    from C:/Program Files (x86)/IronRuby 1.1/Lib/ruby/1.9.1/csv.rb:1818:in `
loop'
    from C:/Program Files (x86)/IronRuby 1.1/Lib/ruby/1.9.1/csv.rb:1818:in `
shift'
    from C:/myproject/myproject/myproject/Program.rb:3
```

I am using Ironruby 1.1.3

I am looking for the correct syntax to get a single line with the headers option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested this in a different engine and this seems to be a bug in Ironruby

Answer (score 0):

You could try this, mind the colsep, adapt it to what you have in your CSV files.
If you want to show the headers:

```
require 'csv'

path = "G:/documents/musicinfo"
Dir.glob("#{path}/**/*.csv").each {|file|
  CSV.foreach(file, :col_sep => ';') do |row|
    puts "#{file} => #{row}"
    break
  end
}
```

Gives as array:

```
G:/documents/musicinfo/album.csv => ["album_release_year", "album_id", "artist_id", "album"]
G:/documents/musicinfo/artist.csv => ["artist_id", "artist_name"]
G:/documents/musicinfo/Copy of all2.csv => ["album_release_year,album_id,track_id,artist_id,artist_name,duration,genre,track_popularity,disc_number,track_number,track,album"]
G:/documents/musicinfo/genres.csv => ["genreId", " genreNaam"]
G:/documents/musicinfo/songs.csv => ["album_id", " track_id", " artist_id", " track_popularity", "genre_id", "track"]
```

And, if you want to show the first datarow or keep it as CSV adapt the above with:

```
CSV.foreach(file, :col_sep => ';', :headers => true) do |row|
```

Which gives:

```
G:/documents/musicinfo/album.csv => 0000,10747312,11522976,Beyond Imagination (Bonus Track Version)
G:/documents/musicinfo/artist.csv => 10000004,Jimi Hendrix
G:/documents/musicinfo/Copy of all2.csv => "2008,12877382,24516577,10000004,Jimi Hendrix,05:39,Pop,9,16,1,10,Free spirit"
G:/documents/musicinfo/genres.csv => 1,Alternative
G:/documents/musicinfo/songs.csv => 12877382,24516577,10000004,9,16,Free spirit
```

Comment: i do not want to iterate on the rows

Comment: then after the first row do a return

Comment: this is not what i want. (i have to get the first row from multiple files, then the second, etc.)

Comment: ah, i adapted my answer to do that, next time, please post some more code so that we have less guessing to do

Comment: well your solution just gives the first row, then i need to get the second, third, etc. anyway i know how to do it myself. my questions is specifically about how to use the shift method with the headers option.

Comment: eyaler, you said in your first comment you don't want to iterate the rows, please be more clear in what you ask. In your example the shift just picks the next file, what in my example the each method does. If you realy want your version to work then please publish it entirely so that i can test it

Comment: the shift method gets the next line not the next file. i want to be able to get a single line without using an each loop. my first example executes correctly. i want to know how to get it to work also with the headers option. i want to know if this is a syntax error or a bug in the csv implementation. i am not looking for workarounds. thanks